# Squid3 enable multipart form data

Tags: squid

I have a client that says he can't upload images with our squid using `Content-Type: multipart / form-data;` and I'm searching for a way to enable that in my config but all I found so far regarding this thing is this line: `acl fileupload req_mime_type -i ^multipart/form-data$` and I'm not very sure what it even means/does?

Any ideas how I may enable this feature for my client?

Answer (score 0):

The config file appears to be correctly set to accept the multipart/form-data mime type. I will propose your client examines closely his request (in the case he is the one generating it) to make sure it follows with HTTP specifications.